# Pandan leaves and stalk turning yellow and soft, why and what do

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, watering, repotting

I'm not sure what plant this is exactly, Plantsnap said it's pandan, but it's been growing fine for about 10 years in mom's dark office, and now 4 years in my kitchen, but recently it started to dry out and yellow. As I understand, the leaves drying out from the tips is normal, but now, the entire leaf goes brown and soft, and today I noticed that the stalk is going brown and yellow and getting softer. I try to water it only when the soil is dry, but I guess I might've watered too much? Or maybe it froze? It can get cold in the kitchen when the wind is getting right in the ventilation system...
What do I do? Let it dry and hope for the best? Should I repot it? If so, do I need to disinfect the pot\soil? Do I try to shake off the soil and clean the roots or should I try to keep the soil 'blob' intact?

Also, what would be the best way to ''make babies'' out of it in case it dies? I picked off little ones off the stem on the bottom and put them in the water but I only managed to get 1 sprout out of 3 before...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: for the lack of options, I did decide to repot it and 
[image]

I forgot my grandma does this ‍♀️

Comment: It is *pandan* I can confirm. I have one too.

Comment: You could try this maybe if you are suspecting root rot and overwatering. https://plantcaretoday.com/hydrogen-peroxide-for-root-rot.html#